# go - Modifying pointer to slice doesn't modify the original

Tags: pointers, go

I try to create a struct where one field is a pointer to the existing empty slice. Then I modify struct's field, and later I try to get the new content from the original slice - but it's still empty!

Here is the demo code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type A struct {
    B []int
}

func main() {
    c := []int{}

    a := &A{
        B: c,
    }

    a.B = append(a.B, 5)

    fmt.Println(c)
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

The result here is:

```
[]
&{[5]}
```

The question is - how do I get the actual slice content from both original slice and struct's field? I have no passing the slice to the function as a param here.

Comment: `B []int` is _not_ a pointer to slice it is a slice. You want `B *[]int`. Take the Tour of Go once more.

Comment: Later I rewrite it with `c` and slices are passed by reference, isn't it?!

Comment: Nothing in Go is passed by reference. Slices contain a pointer to an underlying array.

Comment: @Adrian, ok, can you fix my demo code so it works as expected?

Comment: Read Volker's comment, that is the change to make for this code. I would say that this is pretty unusual (keeping a pointer to a struct field like this) as a use case, and your existing code would be fine in most circumstances (just referencing a field in a pointer to a struct), so this is very possibly an XY Problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a slice of pointers like in example below:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type A struct {
    B *[]int
}

func main() {
    c := []int{}

    a := &A{
        B: &c,
    }

    *a.B = append(*a.B, 4)
    *a.B = append(*a.B, 5)

    fmt.Println(c)

    fmt.Println(a.B)
}
```

Result 
[image: The result is]